# Need to check two propertie in a <target>

Tags: xml, ant

I am using ant and I have two properties:testA and testB, both accept true or false.

In a Target I need to check if both are true, but `<target>` accepts just one if attribute.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<condition>` task to create a new property based on whether the other properties are true.

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-target-multi-conditional" default="run">
    <target name="init">
        <property name="testA" value="true"/>
        <property name="testB" value="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="condition-check">
        <condition property="both-are-true">
            <and>
                <istrue value="${testA}"/>
                <istrue value="${testB}"/>
            </and>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="init,condition-check" if="both-are-true">
        <echo>Both testA and testB are true.</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output

```
init:

condition-check:

run:
     [echo] Both testA and testB are true.
```